# Search Multiple Tables by ID using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Net application i am using ListView which Renders HTML of multiple Tables in browser. what i need is to search by an ID inside table and if ID will be matched then shows the only table which have that ID that was given by an input.

For simplicity i Created JSFiddle in which there are two table when i put chassis no inside textbox then show the table which have matching chassis no id but i am not able to achieve simple task so sorry for this..

[here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/402/)

Here is my rendered HTML in browser

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  find table by Chassis No" style="width:200px"></input>
<br/>
Table 1
<table style="margin-top: 0px;" class="style1">
   <thead>
   </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="makeborder">
       <td style="width: 122px" rowspan="4">       
       </td>
       <td style="width: 140px;">Stock No</td>
       <td style="width: 140px;">6</td>
       <td>Make</td>
       <td>HONDA</td>
       <td> Model</td>
       <td>ACTY</td>
       <td> COLOR </td>
       <td>BAIGE/GREEN</td>
       <td><img src="flags/~\flags\japan.png"></td>
    </tr>
       <tr class="makeborder">
       <td>Price </td>
       <td style="width: 140px;"> 0.0000</td>
       <td>Fuel</td>
      <td>DIESEL</td>
        <td class="coldata">Steering </td>
        <td>LEFT</td>
        <td style="background-color:red; color:white">Chassis No</td>
        <td class="Chassis_No" style="background-color:red; color:white">7894566412</td>
        <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="makeborder">
        <td >Year</td>
        <td style="width: 140px;">2013 </td>
        <td>Mileage</td>
        <td>150</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>TRUCK</td>
        <td>Door/Seat</td>
        <td>3/</td>
        <td></td>
   </tr>
</tbody></table>

Table 2
<table style="margin-top: 0px;" class="style1">
   <thead>
   </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="makeborder">
       <td style="width: 122px" rowspan="4">       
       </td>
       <td style="width: 140px;">Stock No</td>
       <td style="width: 140px;">6</td>
       <td>Make</td>
       <td>HONDA</td>
       <td> Model</td>
       <td>ACTY</td>
       <td> COLOR </td>
       <td>BAIGE/GREEN</td>
       <td><img src="flags/~\flags\japan.png"></td>
    </tr>
       <tr class="makeborder">
       <td>Price </td>
       <td style="width: 140px;"> 0.0000</td>
       <td>Fuel</td>
      <td>DIESEL</td>
        <td class="coldata">Steering </td>
        <td>LEFT</td>
        <td style="background-color:red; color:white">Chassis No</td>
        <td class="Chassis_No"  style="background-color:red; color:white">135498698</td>
        <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="makeborder">
        <td >Year</td>
        <td style="width: 140px;">2013 </td>
        <td>Mileage</td>
        <td>150</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>TRUCK</td>
        <td>Door/Seat</td>
        <td>3/</td>
        <td></td>
   </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

A Script which i am using to achieve this task

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".style1 tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var Chasis_no = $row.find("td .Chassis_No").text();

            if (Chasis_no.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $(".style1").hide();
            }
            else {
                 $(".style1").show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I hope you know that **IDs are supposed to be unique in DOM**. Please try replacing ID with class instead.

Comment: @palaѕн yup you are right i have updated it now.. actually in asp.net application in listview it will crate the multiple ids dynamically with same name but it`s does`t matter i will replace it to class instead of id but now i have updated id to class here

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, ID's are supposed to be unique, whereas classes can be used to select multiple elements.  However, you can make use of *container elements* to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rFGWZ/404/

```
 $("#search").on("keyup", function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $(".style1 tr").each(function (index) {
                if (index !== 0) {

                    $row = $(this);
                    if ($row.find('.Chassis_No').length > 0) {
                        var Chasis_no = $row.find("td.Chassis_No").text();

                        if (Chasis_no.indexOf(value) > -1) {
                            $(this).closest('.style1').show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).closest('.style1').hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different spin, similar idea.

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("table").each(function (index) {
        var chassisNo = $(this).find('.Chassis_No').text();

        if (value !== chassisNo) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Or a really fun way to do it with just selectors :P

```
if (value) {
   $('table .Chassis_No:not([text="' 
      + value + '"])').parents('table').hide();
   $('table .Chassis_No:contains("'
      + value + '")').parents('table').show();
} 
else {
  $('table').show() 
}
```